# How to pass /post JSON array to the server from the client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using jQuery to create a JSON array, and now from the client side how do I  pass or post the JSON array to the server/backend from the modal window?

When i click "Save Changes" on the modal window i want to pass/ post the

`var    data = $(this).serializeObject()` to the server.

How can I go about doing it from the client side using jQuery or javascript?

My code is here in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dev1212/GP2Y6/30/ ( modal window is not showing up in the fiddle when the user click submit but work on my local machine)

Is the right way to go about posting it to the server?

Would this be the right way to pass the JSON array data to the server?

This is my updated version:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',

    url: 'http://re-directb-acktohomepage.com/',
contentType:'application/json'
    data: data,
    success: 
        alert('success');

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `"$.ajax"` and put your json data through the `"data"` parameter. You will get the data in the request object sending to the server.

Cheers

Comment: Would this be the right way to pass the JSON array data to the server?

Comment: Everything in the web applications is based on the HTTP protocol. So one way or another, you will pass the data through the Hyper Text in HTTP. Also yes, it's one of the right ways to do that.

Comment: I just updated the code above let me know if i am doing this correctly.. once i post the json data to the server i am redirecting to some other page.

Comment: Hey man, you are doing two different things together! If you wanna submit a form, it's another story (you should go through postbacks). If you wanna do AJAX thing then don't submit the form. You call the ajax method and then submit the form and form action redirects you to another place.

Comment: i want to submit the modal form window ie post the JSOn to server and redirect to the homepage..

Comment: So put the json string in an input element and get it on the server by submitting the form. Also you can first call the ajax method and after getting the result submit the form. Hope it helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Look into ajax or handling the httprequest yourself. ajax is really easy since you're using jQuery already.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a form and submit it through javascript like [this](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml) or you can use AJAX through jQuery like [this](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml).

One will redirect your page and one will post the data while keeping your browser on the same page. This question has been answered many times on this site so you could also look around for a more in depth answer.